# Livestream background image wont refresh

Tags: javascript, css

I am using a live stream of a webcam for the background image of my personal website and I am having a problem with it auto refreshing every 2 seconds.

Site: [daviddiliberto.com](http://www.daviddiliberto.com)

Feed source:

```
http://207.251.86.238/cctv290.jpg
```

I use Squarespace which uses a theme and my CSS needs to override the theme so I injected it with this here:

```
#main {
background-image: url("http://207.251.86.238/cctv290.jpg");
background-size: cover;
}
```

My JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById("main").style.backgroundImage = "url("
            + "http://207.251.86.238/cctv290.jpg?"
            + new Date().getTime()
            + ")";
    }, 2000);
</script>
```

Any help much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Im not sure that the date/time is even necessary. It's basically the source .jpg is constantly being updated due to the live feed. So i'm looking for a way to constantly update it. Sorry i dont know JS well, not a developer. ;-/

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is an interesting concept (although loading a new image every two seconds is kind of heavy IMO)

Your **main** problem is you're using `setTimeout` (one iteration) when you should be using `setInterval` (multiple/infinite iterations)

I'd also recommend saving the element reference to a variable so it doesn't have to be fetched each iteration. It'd look something like the following

```
var main = document.getElementById("main");
setInterval(function() {
    // Fetch it again
    main.style.backgroundImage = "url(http://207.251.86.238/cctv290.jpg?"
    + new Date().getTime()
    + ")";
}, 2000);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pX3Xz/)

Comment: I'm not sure how to remove the white flash without using two elements of full size and switching them, perhaps someone else can help